# How is the hidden interface bridge100 working?

Tags: macos, network, internet-sharing, mdm

This interface `bridge100` has been introduced with
`Mavericks` and exists on `Yosemite`.
(On `Mountain Lion` the same kind of mechanism was
taking place with the `bridge0` associated with the visible interface: `Thunderbolt Bridge`).

This interface is related to the starting of `Internet Sharing`.
When `Internet Sharing` is off:

```
$ ifconfig bridge100
ifconfig: interface bridge100 does not exist
$
```

When `Internet Sharing` is on:

```
$ ifconfig bridge 100
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICASRT> mtu1500
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        ether ••My_Ethernet_@MAC••
[...]
```

But this interface doesn't appear within `System Preferences > Network`.

---

Where is the correct documentation about this hidden interface?

How to make this interface appear within the `System Preferences > Network` list of interfaces?

How is this interface configuration managed?

Comment: Would this *technical* question be more useful in another Stackexchange group as: "Super User" or "Network Engineering"?

Answer (score 2):

(This is isn't a correct answer, but just a starting point.)

### Not mandatory

This bridge interface is not at all necessary. Here is the way to inactivate it:

- Stop `Internet Sharing` through the GUI.
- Wait one full minute for all the processes to terminate their house keeping:

  ```
  ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|Int)'
  ```
- modify the `Internet Sharing` plist:

  ```
  cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
  /usr/bin/sudo -s
  # make a quick backup
  cp com.apple.NetworkSharing.plist com.apple.NetworkSharing.plist~orig
  vi com.apple.NetworkSharing.plist
  ```

  within the `ProgramArguments` array, insert the 2 new arguments `-B` (disable bridge interface) and `-v` (verbose output), so that this array definition will look like:

  ```
  <array>
      <string>/usr/libexec/InternetSharing</string>
      <string>-B</string>
      <string>-v</string>
  </array>
  ```

  save this new file and exit `vi`
- start `Internet Sharing` through the GUI,
- do a verification `ifconfig -a`.

Now `Internet Sharing` is directly working on `en1` and all necessary processes are started correctly: `pfctl`, `wifid`, `natpmpd`, `bootpd`.